# How to check the fine motor skills development

Tags: primary-schooler, fine-motor-skills, gross-motor-development

My son is 8 yrs and has had problems with his motor skills. In particular, he had difficulties holding a pencil. He is now writing beautifully, but still hesitates to write and draw. When eating, he avoids tearing his roti (a kind of Indian bread) and dosas (a sort of crepe like meal) and takes a lot of time to eat rice with a spoon. He is comfortable punching pillow cushions and always wants to press the palms, which gives him stress relief. In the mornings, I find that he is not fresh enough even after 10 hrs of sleep. He does not enjoying brushing his teeth and while bathing he applies soap very lightly. Opening the doors seems to be a little difficult... Friends tell me that these problems are all related to each other and that I should consult somebody. Does anyone have any suggestions? Incidentally, I am also the mother of 16 year old daughter.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely see your doctor if possible. At 8 years of age some of these seem to be a concern. There's not enough information to really know whats going on. It could be an allergy or allergies, an illness, a form of hyper-sensitivity,  or simply his personality.

Here is a group of documents curated by the US National Institutes for Health that will give you a lot of material to review on typical developmental milestones:

[Middle Childhood (6-8 years of age)](http://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/childdevelopment/positiveparenting/middle.html)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have your child assessed by an Occupational Therapist.

If you're located in the United States Public Law 94-142 (IDEA) ensures that your child has access to special education if he qualifies.  Speak to your child's school about your concerns.